# How to CLOSE a context menu after a timeout?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I need to have a context menu (currently created with TrackPopupMenu) close automatically after a period of inactivity.  I'm trying to search but only finding the opposite (how to *activate* a popup after a timeout) or specialized things for particular applications.  The only things I've found that is even close is to enumerate the children of the desktop until a window with class name #32768 is found -- that will be the menu -- and close it.

I'm hoping for a better, clearer way.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Normally you never need to close a popup menu until it looses focus. This is reasonable as you never know how fast someone reads or needs to find the correct entry. If you need to have info vanish after some time create a small borderless winow. This way you have complete control over it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send [`WM_CANCELMODE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  message to the parent window that host the  context menu .

Comment: Thanks!  That was what I didn't know.  So many messages, for such a small mind!  (Mine, of course)

Comment: Raymond Chen blogged a series on UI modality, which included implementing timeouts for message boxes, which is similar to your problem.  If you want to learn the gory details, study these, starting here:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/18/376080.aspx