# Close popup menu programmatically on Windows

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a simple example for creating popup menu. I want to close this menu programmatically when pressing on button, is there any possibility to do that? Or maybe I should use different class?

I need to open this menu when button is pressed and close it the same way when pressing the button. Here is simple code example that I have.

```
#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
#define IDM_FILE_NEW 1
#define IDM_FILE_OPEN 2
#define IDM_FILE_QUIT 3

#define BUTTON_ID 1

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

HWND gButton = NULL;
HWND mainHwnd = NULL;
HMENU hMenu;
bool gMenuHidden = false;

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_POPUPMENU, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_POPUPMENU));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_POPUPMENU));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   mainHwnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!mainHwnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(mainHwnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(mainHwnd);

   return TRUE;
}

HMENU CreateAndInitializeMenu()
{
    HMENU menu = CreatePopupMenu();

    AppendMenuW(menu, MF_STRING, IDM_FILE_NEW, L"&New");
    AppendMenuW(menu, MF_STRING, IDM_FILE_OPEN, L"&Open");
    AppendMenuW(menu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, NULL);
    AppendMenuW(menu, MF_STRING, IDM_FILE_QUIT, L"&Quit");

    return menu;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message) {
        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            if (wParam == BUTTON_ID)
            {
                //gMenuHidden = !gMenuHidden;
                if (gMenuHidden)
                {
                    hMenu = CreateAndInitializeMenu();

                    TrackPopupMenu(hMenu, TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, 150, 250, 0, mainHwnd, NULL);
                    DestroyMenu(hMenu);
                }
                else
                {
                    // TODO:
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            
            gButton = CreateWindowW(L"button", L"Show/Hide menu", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 100, 120, 120, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)BUTTON_ID, NULL, NULL);
            break;
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Maybe the right way is to always create menu when button is pressed and destroy it right after that? But in that case we should create menu all the time when pressing the button. I was trying to create the menu once and show it when we need it. Also the menu is not shown right now. Trying to figure out why.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can certainly avoid repeating the creation/destruction of your popup menu: just create it (once) on window creation (by  handling the `WM_CREATE` message) and destroy it when handling `WM_DESTROY`. But note: you will need to make your `hMenu` a `static` variable, so that its value is maintained across multiple calls of your `WndProc` function.

As for hiding the menu programmatically – you can do this by sending the parent window the `WM_CANCELMODE` message, as suggested in this related question: [How to CLOSE a context menu after a timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19226173/10871073)

You can keep a 'flag' variable (also must be `static`) to keep track of the current display status of the popup menu: if this is *not* shown, call `TrackPopupMenu`; if it *is* shown, send the `WM_CANCELMODE` message. You will also need to add the `TPM_RETURNCMD` flag in your call to `TrackPopupMenu`, so that you can reset the flag if/when the user selects a command from the menu.

Here's a version of your `WndProc` function that implements this approach:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HMENU hMenu;     // Make "static" so we can reuse across calls
    static bool hasMenu = false; // Flag to indicate current menu status
    POINT point;
    switch (msg) {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
                case IDM_FILE_NEW:
                case IDM_FILE_OPEN:
                    MessageBeep(MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                    break;
                case IDM_FILE_QUIT:
                    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case WM_CREATE:
            // Create the menu (once only) on window creation...
            hMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
            AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_FILE_NEW, L"&New");
            AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_FILE_OPEN, L"&Open");
            AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, NULL);
            AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_FILE_QUIT, L"&Quit");
            hasMenu = false; // Reset here in case of multiple uses.
            break;
        case WM_RBUTTONUP:
            if (!hasMenu) { // Only show menu if it's not already active...
                hasMenu = true;
                point.x = LOWORD(lParam);
                point.y = HIWORD(lParam);
                ClientToScreen(hwnd, &point);
                // Add the "TPM_RETURNCMD" flag so we can reset "hasMenu" when a command is sselected (return non-zero):
                BOOL cmd = TrackPopupMenu(hMenu, TPM_RIGHTBUTTON | TPM_RETURNCMD, point.x, point.y, 0, hwnd, NULL);
                if (cmd) {
                    hasMenu = false;
                    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_COMMAND, cmd, 0); // Send the command (not done automatically with TPM_RETURNCMD)
                }
            }
            else {
                hasMenu = false;
                SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CANCELMODE, 0, 0);
            }
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            DestroyMenu(hMenu); // Destroy the menu.
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
    }
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I updated my answer and code with the latest one. In general yes, I think this is exactly that I want in your code. But why the menu is not shown for me? Is that correct to destroy it all the time?

Comment: @Oleg - Updated. From the tests I've done, this seems to achieve what your asking: single create/destroy and the menu goes away if the right button is clicked when it's already active.

Comment: @Oleg Also, I'm not sure what you mean that your menu isn't shown. Using your (original) code, I see the popup menu when I *release* the right mouse button.

Comment: By the way why I could not call CreatePopupMenu() from any other place except WM_CREATE event?

Comment: You can call it from lots of different places (like on program initialization) but then you would need the `hMenu` to be 'global'. It just seemed that on window creation seemed like the logical place to do it.

Comment: I had an annoying system menu showing up instead of the custom popup menu we had plans to show. Thanks to you, I managed to use my menu as intended, using the WM_CANCELMODE in OnInitMenuPopup when the bSysMenu bool was set to true.